# curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Tags: ssl, curl, https

I am trying to connect my remote nginx server which is configured to use ssl.

I fired a command

```
$curl  https://10.73.80.197:8080/
```

but after that i am getting error. Here is the whole log-

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 10.73.80.197...
* Connected to 10.73.80.197 (10.73.80.197) port 80 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

Comment: Are you sure that your server is configured to use SSL at port 8080? This is a port typically associated with HTTP only (i.e. no SSL). Have you tried with a web browser?

Comment: yah..... here is my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/docker-registry  file                       # For versions of Nginx > 1.3.9 that include chunked transfer encoding support
# Replace with appropriate values where necessary

upstream docker-registry {
 server localhost:5000;
}

server {
 listen 8080;
 server_name gslab.dockerregistry.com;

 ssl on;
 ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/gslab-docker-registry.com.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/gslab-docker-registry.com.key;

...................

Comment: Hello Steffen,                                                                                              I am following article at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-14-04.                    The problem is solved. I checked firewall configuration on server and allowed  port 8080 by using ufw commands. Now its fine n in working state.             Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 7):

as explained in several other articles:

[curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840101/curl-35-error1408f10bssl-routinesssl3-get-recordwrong-version-number)

[Curl returns "Unknown protocol"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619468/curl-returns-unknown-protocol)

this kind of curl error is often the result of using a web proxy over https instead of http

you should check your **https_proxy** env variable

if you have something like

> https://myproxy.example.com:8080/

then you should change and set the following

> https_proxy=**http**://myproxy.example.com:8080/

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this today and in my case it was a misconfiguration in my `nginx.conf` file. My configuration contained something like this:

```
server {
    listen       443;
    listen       [::]:443;
    # Single underscore means 'matches any server name'
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Only allow more recent (still secure) versions of TLS
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    # Explicitly set list of supported ciphers
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256-CBC:ECDH+AES128-CBC:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

    ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/atmloader/server.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/atmloader/server.pem";

    # ...
}
```

but it should have looked like this:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl;
    # Single underscore means 'matches any server name'
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Only allow more recent (still secure) versions of TLS
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    # Explicitly set list of supported ciphers
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256-CBC:ECDH+AES128-CBC:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

    ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/atmloader/server.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/atmloader/server.pem";

    # ...
}
```

Notice the missing `ssl` in the `listen` parameter values.

A copy-and-paste mistake on my part when copying configuration that was originally created for a non-HTTPS port.