# node errors: SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol and SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

Tags: node.js, post, https

Alright, this very same problem has been asked in the past but with no satisfactory answer; at least for my end. Long story short, using `curl` for posting data to a remote (note: `https`) server with the following works:

```
curl -X POST 'https://a.b.c.d/somewhere/' --data 'somedata' --header "Content-Type: text/turtle" -i
```

Now, the time comes to do the same thing using node. My functions work fine and if instead of using the https module I use the http module I get a message that I have to try again for https. So, I am using https in order to make the request, with the options below:

```
var myOptions = {
    hostname : "a.b.c.d",
    port     : "80",
    path     : "/somewhere/",
    method   : 'POST',
    headers  : {
        'Content-Type'   : 'text/turtle', 
        'Content-Length' : message.length
        },
    secureProtocol : 'SSLv3_method'
};
```

where by the way I have also checked that curl works fine when passing the parameter `--sslv3`.

However, using the above options I get the following error

```
140735237133072:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:787:
```

If on top of my code I put a statement of the form (idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421050/node-request-getting-error-ssl23-get-server-hellounknown-protocol/21035725#21035725))

```
https.globalAgent.options.secureProtocol = 'SSLv3_method';
```

then actually the error message changes to

```
140735237133072:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:338:
```

I find this unexpected as I have already indicated in the options part that I want `SSLv3_method` to be used as the protocol. In any case, how would I be able to reproduce the behavior of `curl` from command line where everything is working?

Finally, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421050/node-request-getting-error-ssl23-get-server-hellounknown-protocol/18142862#18142862) it is mentioned that port 80 might be a wrong port for using it with https. Is this really true? Why would `curl` work anyway? If it is true, do you know why, or can you point me to the right direction for understanding the problem?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have `port: 443,` or just leave it unset since 443 is the default port when using the `https` module, instead of `port: "80"`.

cURL works without a port because it knows that `https://` is port 443 by default. You *can* pass in a url to [`https.request()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) as the first argument (like cURL), but then you can't customize `method`, `headers`, or anything else that can't be determined from a URL alone.