# error while installing indiapay in laravel

Tags: php, ssl, laravel-5

I need to implement payment gateway in php laravel framework.so i downloaded indiapay from github and ran this command "composer require softon/indipay" .I got

[Composer\Downloader \TransportException]
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
  error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
  Failed to enable crypto
  failed to open stream: operation failed

How to fix this?

Comment: Do you have any custom config in composer.json?

Comment: Highly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421050/node-request-getting-error-ssl23-get-server-hellounknown-protocol