# Jupyterlab and Plotly offline: requirejs is not defined

Tags: python, requirejs, plotly, jupyter-lab

I installed plot.ly using conda and tried to use it in offline mode on Jupyterlab:

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

The Firefox developer console displays the following error after those statements:

```
ReferenceError: requirejs is not defined
```

I tried to manually put `require.js` into the folder with the notebook and into `...\anaconda3\pkgs\jupyter\nbextensions`, it didn't work.

How do I solve this issue? How do I install require.js properly?

Versions:

- Python 3.6.6
- Plotly 3.4.2
- Jupyterlab 0.35.4
- Windows 10
- Firefox 64.0.2
- nodejs 10.15.0

Comment: Hello Khris, did you install Jupyter Lab's plotly extension? Unlike in Jupyter Notebook, plotly plots won't work directly in Jupyter Lab. You need to install his extension:
https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyter-renderers/tree/master/packages/plotly-extension

Comment: Hi byouness, I did not, thanks for telling me this. Sadly I can't install it, getting this error: `write EPROTO 1172:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:252:`. I'm behind a company proxy, so that might be a reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Please see [Yan Ulms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12193584/yan-ulm) answer: the plotly extension for Jupyter Lab is deprecated**

---

**Old answer:**

You need to install the [plotly extension for Jupyter Lab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyter-renderers/tree/master/packages/plotly-extension), as mentioned by @byouness.

A common pitfall in the installation is that you need to have a recent Node.js installation. This might be the cause of your error `write EPROTO 1172:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:252`. Re-installing Node.js might be an easy fix.

Your company firewall might indeed be a problem. Because the installation of the extension uses NPM (node.je package manager), you should check [Common proxy and networking problems](https://npm.community/t/common-proxy-and-networking-problems/151/2) for NPM. You might need to install the extension manually, by following the [installation instructions for developers](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyter-renderers/tree/master/packages/plotly-extension#install-1).

I definitely agree that the process is much more difficult than it should be. Installing it at my company was also a struggle. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I managed to configure the proxies but I'm still getting the wrong version error. The requirements say node.js > 5 and I have 10.15.0, so this makes no sense. I'll ask that question on their github.

Comment: Hello Khris. Great! If the only error you have is linked to node.js, then try using a node.js version previous to 10 (v8.9.3 for example). I believe there might be some issues with versions 10 and higher depending on the JupyterLab and plotly extension versions you're installing: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4986

Comment: Many thanks for finding this, I will try with another version.

Comment: @byouness I did install v8.15.0 and now I'm getting a different error: `request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@jupyterlab%2fplotly-extension failed, reason: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:827:`. Been looking through some threads like https://github.com/jspm/github/issues/59 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421050/node-request-getting-error-ssl23-get-server-hellounknown-protocol and set strict-ssl to false, but that didn't solve it. Probably an issue with the company proxy server.

Comment: Too bad. I unfortunately can't help with this. I hope @pj.dewitte who did a similar installation behind a company proxy wll be able to help!

Comment: Sorry no, this is beyond my knowledge and experience... Thinking out of the box: is it possible to take the computer/laptop out of the firewall zone (e.g. use your phone as a hotspot)? Another exotic idea, is to do the install on another computer, and copy the installation via a memory stick.

Comment: at the moment extension link mentioned returns 404

Answer (score 3):

The JupyterLab readme on GitHub says that the [@jupyterlab/plotly-extension](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jupyterlab/plotly-extension) is being **deprecated**. Please **use the Plotly-supported [jupyterlab-plotly](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jupyterlab-plotly)**. See the [plotly.py README](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py#jupyterlab-support-python-35) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default='iframe'
```

This worked for me as suggested by an answer here https://github.com/plotly/plotly_express/issues/38#issuecomment-826602624